# Python multiplication

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matrix Multiplication in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508021/matrix-multiplication-in-python)

I already wrote a program can multiply two matrices. But these code doesn't work if two matrix have different columns(wrong answer).

```
C = [[4,1,9], [6,2,8], [7,3,5]]
D = [[2,9], [5,2], [1,0]]
M=[] 
for i in range(len(C)):
     Z.append([])
        for j in range(len(D[0])):
            Z[i].append(0)
            for k in range(len(D[0])):
                M[i][j]+=C[i][k]*D[k][j]
print (M)
```

Comment: That can't possibly run. What is Z?

Comment: result should be [[22, 38],[30,58],[34,69]], but my result is [[13, 38],[22,58],[29,69]]

Comment: You can't multiply together a 3x3 and a 2x2 matrix - the number of columns in the first matrix must equal the number of rows of the second. Also, why do you think you should get 22 as the first element of the first list in the result? What things are multiplied together and added to get that value?

Comment: @Whatang: The D matrix is 3x2, so multiplying by it does make sense.

Comment: Oops, how on earth did I miss that? Doh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is other version using numpy](http://www.cv.nrao.edu/~aleroy/pytut/topic1/intro_numpy_math.py)

Well I was just putting a little code, but here you are the whole code:

```
# matrices.py
# This optional case study solves each of the following problems.  Each
# solution uses the solutions to the preceding problems.

# 1) Multiply two matrices
# 2) Invert a matrix
# 3) Solve a system of linear equations
# 4) Fit an exact polynomial to a list of points
# 5) Find the coefficients of the polynomial for a power sum

# This last problem needs a little explaining.  Consider this power sum:
# 1 + 2 + ... + n.  We know this equals n(n+1)/2.  We can represent this
# quadratic function by its coefficients alone, as [1/2, 1/2, 0] (ignoring
# integer division in this explanation).

# Now, the sum of the squares is: 1**2 + 2**2 + ... + n**2.  This is a cubic
# equation.  It happens to be [1/3, 1/2, 1/6, 0].  That is:
# 1**2 + ... + n**2 = (1/3)n**3 + (1/2)n**2 + (1/6)n

# In fact, for positive integer k, 1**k + ... + n**k is a (k+1)-degree
# polynomial.  The problem we are solving is to write a function which takes
# this number k, and returns the coefficients of that polynomial.

# Also, our approach for matrix multiplication needs some slight explaining.
# We basically use Gauss-Jordan Elimination to get reduced row echelon form
# while applying the same elementary row operations to an identity matrix -- in
# so doing, the identity matrix is transformed into the inverse of the original
# matrix.  Amazing!

import copy
from fractions import Fraction

def copyMatrix(m):
    return copy.deepcopy(m)

def makeIdentity(n):
    result = make2dList(n,n)
    for i in xrange(n):
        result[i][i] = Fraction(1, 1)
    return result

def testMakeIdentity():
    print "Testing makeIdentity...",
    i3 = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
    assert(i3 == makeIdentity(3))
    print "Passed!"

def multiplyMatrices(a, b):
    # confirm dimensions
    aRows = len(a)
    aCols = len(a[0])
    bRows = len(b)
    bCols = len(b[0])
    assert(aCols == bRows) # belongs in a contract 
    rows = aRows
    cols = bCols
    # create the result matrix c = a*b
    c = make2dList(rows, cols)
    # now find each value in turn in the result matrix
    for row in xrange(rows):
        for col in xrange(cols):
            dotProduct = Fraction(0, 1)
            for i in xrange(aCols):
                dotProduct += a[row][i]*b[i][col]
            c[row][col] = dotProduct
    return c

def testMultiplyMatrices():
    print "Testing multiplyMatrices...",
    a = [ [ 1, 2, 3],
          [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]
    b = [ [ 0, 3],
          [ 1, 4],
          [ 2, 5] ]
    c = [ [ 8, 26],
          [17, 62 ] ]
    observedC = multiplyMatrices(a, b)
    assert(observedC == c)
    print "Passed!"

def multiplyRowOfSquareMatrix(m, row, k):
    n = len(m)
    rowOperator = makeIdentity(n)
    rowOperator[row][row] = k
    return multiplyMatrices(rowOperator, m)

def testMultiplyRowOfSquareMatrix():
    print "Testing multiplyRowOfSquareMatrix...",
    a = [ [ 1, 2 ],
          [ 4, 5  ] ]
    assert(multiplyRowOfSquareMatrix(a, 0, 5) == [[5, 10], [4, 5]])
    assert(multiplyRowOfSquareMatrix(a, 1, 6) == [[1, 2], [24, 30]])
    print "Passed!"

def addMultipleOfRowOfSquareMatrix(m, sourceRow, k, targetRow):
    # add k * sourceRow to targetRow of matrix m
    n = len(m)
    rowOperator = makeIdentity(n)
    rowOperator[targetRow][sourceRow] = k
    return multiplyMatrices(rowOperator, m)

def testAddMultipleOfRowOfSquareMatrix():
    print "Testing addMultipleOfRowOfSquareMatrix...",
    a = [ [ 1, 2 ],
          [ 4, 5  ] ]
    assert(addMultipleOfRowOfSquareMatrix(a, 0, 5, 1) == [[1, 2], [9, 15]])
    assert(addMultipleOfRowOfSquareMatrix(a, 1, 6, 0) == [[25, 32], [4, 5]])
    print "Passed!"

def invertMatrix(m):
    n = len(m)
    assert(len(m) == len(m[0]))
    inverse = makeIdentity(n) # this will BECOME the inverse eventually
    for col in xrange(n):
        # 1. make the diagonal contain a 1
        diagonalRow = col
        assert(m[diagonalRow][col] != 0) # @TODO: actually, we could swap rows
                                         # here, or if no other row has a 0 in
                                         # this column, then we have a singular
                                         # (non-invertible) matrix.  Let's not
                                         # worry about that for now.  :-)
        k = Fraction(1,m[diagonalRow][col])
        m = multiplyRowOfSquareMatrix(m, diagonalRow, k)
        inverse = multiplyRowOfSquareMatrix(inverse, diagonalRow, k)
        # 2. use the 1 on the diagonal to make everything else
        #    in this column a 0
        sourceRow = diagonalRow
        for targetRow in xrange(n):
            if (sourceRow != targetRow):
                k = -m[targetRow][col]
                m = addMultipleOfRowOfSquareMatrix(m, sourceRow, k, targetRow)
                inverse = addMultipleOfRowOfSquareMatrix(inverse, sourceRow,
                                                         k, targetRow)
    # that's it!
    return inverse

def testInvertMatrix():
    print "Testing invertMatrix...",
    a = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 4, 5  ] ]
    aInverse = invertMatrix(a)
    identity = makeIdentity(len(a))
    assert (almostEqualMatrices(identity, multiplyMatrices(a, aInverse)))
    a = [ [ 1, 2, 3], [ 2, 5, 7 ], [3, 4, 8 ] ]
    aInverse = invertMatrix(a)
    identity = makeIdentity(len(a))
    assert (almostEqualMatrices(identity, multiplyMatrices(a, aInverse)))
    print "Passed!"

def solveSystemOfEquations(A, b):
    return multiplyMatrices(invertMatrix(A), b)

def testSolveSystemOfEquations():
    print "Testing solveSystemOfEquations...",
    # 3x + 2y - 2z = 10
    # 2x - 4y + 8z =  0
    # 4x + 4y - 7z = 13
    # x = 2, y = 3, z = 1
    A = [ [3,  2, -2],
          [2, -4,  8],
          [4,  4, -7] ]
    b = [ [ 10 ],
          [  0 ],
          [ 13 ] ]
    observedX = solveSystemOfEquations(A,b)
    expectedX = [ [ 2 ],
                  [ 3 ],
                  [ 1 ] ]
    assert(almostEqualMatrices(observedX, expectedX))
    print "Passed!"

def fitExactPolynomial(pointList):
    n = len(pointList)
    degree = n - 1
    # 1. make A
    A = make2dList(n,n)
    for row in xrange(n):
        for col in xrange(n):
            x = pointList[row][0]
            exponent = degree - col
            A[row][col] = x**exponent
    # 2. make b
    b = make2dList(n,1)
    for row in xrange(n):
        y = pointList[row][1]
        b[row][0] = y
    # use system solver to find solution
    return solveSystemOfEquations(A, b)

def testFitExactPolynomial():
    print "Testing fitPolynomialExactly...",
    def f(x): return 3*x**3 + 2*x**2 + 4*x + 1
    expected = [[3], [2], [4], [1]]
    pointList = [(1,f(1)), (2,f(2)), (5,f(5)), (-3,f(-3))]
    observed = fitExactPolynomial(pointList)
    assert(almostEqualMatrices(observed, expected))    
    print "Passed!"

def findCoefficientsOfPowerSum(k):
    # Assume f(n) = 1**k + ... + n**k
    # We argued by handwaving-ish-calculusy-stuff that f(n) is
    # a polynomial of degree (k+1)
    # We need (k+2) points to fit just such a polynomial
    pointList = []
    y = 0    
    for n in xrange(1,k+3):
        x = Fraction(n, 1)
        # y = 1**k + ... + n**k
        y += x**k
        pointList += [(x,y)]
    return fitExactPolynomial(pointList)

def testFindCoefficientsOfPowerSum():
    print "Testing findCoefficientsOfPowerSum..."
    # Not a formal test here, just printing the answers.
    # Check here for expected values:
    # http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html
    for k in xrange(10):
        print "k = %d:" % k,
        printMatrix(findCoefficientsOfPowerSum(k))
    print "Passed!"

def almostEqualMatrices(m1, m2):
    # verifies each element in the two matrices are almostEqual to each other
    # (and that the two matrices have the same dimensions).
    if (len(m1) != len(m2)): return False
    if (len(m1[0]) != len(m2[0])): return False
    for row in xrange(len(m1)):
        for col in xrange(len(m1[0])):
            if not almostEqual(m1[row][col], m2[row][col]):
                return False
    return True

def almostEqual(d1, d2):
    epsilon = 0.00001
    return abs(d1 - d2) < epsilon

def make2dList(rows, cols):
    a=[]
    for row in xrange(rows): a += [[0]*cols]
    return a

def printMatrix(a):
    def valueStr(value):
        if (isinstance(value, Fraction)):
            (num, den) = (value.numerator, value.denominator)
            if ((num == 0) or (den == 1)): return str(num)
            else: return str(num) + "/" + str(den)
        else:
            return str(value)
    def maxItemLength(a):
        maxLen = 0
        rows = len(a)
        cols = len(a[0])
        for row in xrange(rows):
            for col in xrange(cols):
                maxLen = max(maxLen, len(valueStr(a[row][col])))
        return maxLen
    if (a == []):
        # So we don't crash accessing a[0]
        print []
        return
    rows = len(a)
    cols = len(a[0])
    fieldWidth = maxItemLength(a)
    print "[",
    for row in xrange(rows):
        if (row > 0) and (len(a[row-1]) > 1): print "\n  ",
        print "[",
        for col in xrange(cols):
            if (col > 0): print ",",
            # The next 2 lines print a[row][col] with the given fieldWidth
            format = "%" + str(fieldWidth) + "s"
            print format % valueStr(a[row][col]),
        print "]",
    print "]"


def main():
    testMakeIdentity()
    testMultiplyMatrices()
    testMultiplyRowOfSquareMatrix()
    testAddMultipleOfRowOfSquareMatrix()
    testInvertMatrix()
    testSolveSystemOfEquations()
    testFitExactPolynomial()
    testFindCoefficientsOfPowerSum()

main()
```

Comment: This code always makes matrices of values that are `Fraction` instances, which may not be desirable. To avoid that, you can do `dotProduct = sum(a[row][i]*b[i][col] for i in xrange(aCols))` in the multiplication code, which should preserve the types of the matrices passed in (so multiplying two matrices with `int` values will give a result who's values are also `int`s).

Comment: Yeah, I added a version which includes numpy

Answer (score 2):

In your last loop, you want `k` to go from up to `len(D)` or `len(C[0])` (which must be equal or the multiplication doesn't make any sense). Here's a minimal modification of your code that fixes it:

```
C = [[4,1,9], [6,2,8], [7,3,5]]
D = [[2,9], [5,2], [1,0]]

assert(len(C[0]) == len(D))      # sanity check!
M=[] 
for i in range(len(C)):
    M.append([])
    for j in range(len(D[0])):
        M[i].append(0)
        for k in range(len(D)):  # fixed value
            M[i][j]+=C[i][k]*D[k][j]
print (M)
```

Answer (score 1):

OMG，just change the `D` in `for k in range(len(D[0])):` into `C`. The program would work. Thank you guys!