# matrix using python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm writing a program fro matrix but there is a problem I don't know to get the right output and I need help with it.
this is the question:Given a nXn matrix A and a kXn matrix B find AB .
and here is what I have so far. Thank you in advance

```
def matrixmult (A, B):
    rows_A = len(A)
    cols_A = len(A[0])
    rows_B = len(B)
    cols_B = len(B[0])

    if cols_A != rows_B:
      print "Cannot multiply the two matrices. Incorrect dimensions."
      return

    # Create the result matrix
    # Dimensions would be rows_A x cols_B
    C = [[0 for row in range(cols_B)] for col in range(rows_A)]
    print C

    for i in range(rows_A):
        for j in range(cols_B):
            for k in range(cols_A):
                C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j]
    return C
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong here. Do you have an example input where it gets the wrong answer?

Comment: no actually, but when I run it I get no output!

Comment: When you say you get no output, do you mean it doesn't print anything, that the return value is `None`, or something else? Oh, and in the code you posted, `return C` should be on column 4 instead of 3. Typo in your post?

Comment: it returns value none

Comment: If cols_A != rows_B it will return `None`

Comment: @Mido what is the input you for which you are getting None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function:

```
def matrixmult (A, B):
    rows_A = len(A)
    cols_A = len(A[0])
    rows_B = len(B)
    cols_B = len(B[0])

    if cols_A != rows_B:
      print "Cannot multiply the two matrices. Incorrect dimensions."
      return

    # Create the result matrix
    # Dimensions would be rows_A x cols_B
    C = [[0 for row in range(cols_B)] for col in range(rows_A)]
    print C

    for i in range(rows_A):
        for j in range(cols_B):
            for k in range(cols_A):
                C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j]
    return C
```

Which appears to be the same as [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508133/298607).

If I run this:

```
matrix=[[1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]]

print matrixmult(matrix, matrix)    # that is your function...
```

It returns:

```
[[30, 36, 42], [66, 81, 96], [102, 126, 150]]
```

This is the same as Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array(matrix)
b=np.array(matrix)
print np.dot(a,b)
#  [[ 30  36  42]
    [ 66  81  96]
    [102 126 150]]
```

And the same as the matrix multiply more tersely stated:

```
def mult(mtx_a,mtx_b):
    tpos_b = zip( *mtx_b)
    rtn = [[ sum( ea*eb for ea,eb in zip(a,b)) for b in tpos_b] for a in mtx_a]
    return rtn
```

So -- it is probably your input data that is the issue.

Comment: yeah that was my issue, you're really explained it well Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use numPy library to solve your problem.

> import numpy as np
>
> x = np.array( ((2,3), (3, 5)) )
>
> y = np.array( ((1,2), (5, -1)) )
>
> print x * y

array([[ 2,  6],
       [15, -5]])

More examples:
http://www.python-course.eu/matrix_arithmetic.php

Download numPy:
http://scipy.org/Download

Comment: While `numpy` is definitely the way to go in production code, I'm pretty sure this is an exercise, so going right to a library might defeat the purpose.  Moreover, the OP is doing matrix multiplication, not elementwise multiplication, so `x*y` on two `ndarray`s wouldn't work.  You'd need to use `dot` or the `matrix` class.

Comment: Mido you need to go to numpy website and download the numpy library. Afther you need install and now you can go to your project and do the import.

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
def matrixmult(m1, m2):
    return [
        [sum(x * y for x, y in zip(m1_r, m2_c)) for m2_c in zip(*m2)] for m1_r in m1
    ]
```

Explanation:

> zip(*m2) - gets a column from the second matrix
>
> zip(m1_r, m2_c) - creates tuple from m1 row and m2 column
>
> sum(...) - sums multiplication row * col

Test:

```
m1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
m2 = [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]
result = matrixmult(m1, m2)
assert result == [[58, 64], [139, 154]]
```