# Python matrix query - must be simpler way

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, simplify

I have created a small Python program to multiply two 2 by 2 matrices but am wondering if it could be simplified in any way (particularly the creation of new arrays)

The python code is below:

```
matA=[0]*2
matB=[0]*2
matC=[0]*2
matC[0]=[0]*2
matC[1]=[0]*2
# creating new arrays for multiplying two 2 by 2 matrices
# must be a more simple way


def multiply2by2matrices(a,b):

    matC[0][0]=a[0][0]*b[0][0]+a[0][1]*b[1][0]
    matC[0][1]=a[0][0]*b[0][1]+a[0][1]*b[1][1]
    matC[1][0]=a[1][0]*b[0][0]+a[1][1]*b[1][0]
    matC[1][1]=a[1][0]*b[0][1]+a[1][1]*b[1][1]

    print ((matC[0][0]),(matC[0][1]))
    print ((matC[1][0]),(matC[1][1]))

matA[0]=[4,3]
matA[1]=[2,12]

matB[0]=[5,-2]
matB[1]=[6,3]

multiply2by2matrices(matA, matB)
```

Any thoughts will be greatly received.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508021/matrix-multiplication-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Don't implement by hand. You are reinventing the wheel and there very good wheels around already.

Numpy is the answer.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(20).reshape(5,4)
b = (np.arange(20) + 10).reshape(4,5)
np.dot(a,b)
```

Docs:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Cheers, P

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are required to use only vanilla python it would be much simpler to use numpy. You can use the matrix class or just use 2d arrays and the dot function. For example:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,1],[2,2]])
b=np.array([[3,3],[3,3]])
c=np.dot(a,b)
```

produces:

```
array([[ 6,  6],
       [12, 12]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely simplify matrix multiplication and make it general. The trick is to use `zip`. There are other methods of course, but I think zip might produce some of the cleaner code. 
I didn't test the following, but I think my linear algebra serves me right.

```
def matmult(a,b):
    zipb = zip(*b)
    return [[sum(ax*bx for ax,bx in zip(rowa, colb)) for colb in zipb] for rowa in a]
```

If you don't use a list comprehension you're going to need to pre-allocate a list or use append/extend in between for loops.