# Matrix multiplication of a list of lists

Tags: loops, python-3.x, recursion

This question is a bit tricky for me.The input is a  list of lists like:

```
matmult([[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,0],[0,1]])
```

Output:

```
matmult([[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,0],[0,1]])

[[1,2],[3,4]]

matmult([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]])

[[14, 32], [32, 77]]
```

Here's my broken code for the same:

```
def matmult(m1,m2):
    x=0
    y=0
    a=0
    for value in range(0,len(m1)):
        for other in range(0,len(m2)):
            a=m1[value]*other[value]+other[value]*m2[value]
            return(a)
```

where `matmult` is the name of my function.

Do help me.

Comment: its all wrong first try to understand the concept of matrix multiplication
to implement in python look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508021/matrix-multiplication-in-python

Comment: Please describe the exact problem you're having (including traceback if you're getting an error).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.