# Iterating through and operating on Sympy Matrices

Tags: matrix, sympy, matrix-multiplication

My modified block of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508021/matrix-multiplication-in-python) works for XOR'ing python lists via using functions (XOR and AND) of the Sympy library (first block of code below). However, I am stumped on how to iterate via sympy matrices (second block of code below).

The python lists code that works is:

```
from sympy import And, Xor
from sympy.logic import SOPform, simplify_logic
from sympy import symbols
def LogMatrixMult (A, B):
    rows_A = len(A)
    cols_A = len(A[0])
    rows_B = len(B)
    cols_B = len(B[0])

    if cols_A != rows_B:
      print ("Cannot multiply the two matrices. Incorrect dimensions.")
      return

    # Create the result matrix
    # Dimensions would be rows_A x cols_B
    C = [[0 for row in range(cols_B)] for col in range(rows_A)]
    for i in range(rows_A):
        for j in range(cols_B):
            for k in range(cols_A):
                # I can add Sympy's in simplify_logic(-)
                C[i][j] = Xor(C[i][j], And(A[i][k], B[k][j]))
    return C
b, c, d, e, f, w, x, y, z = symbols('b c d e f w x y z')
m1 = [[b,c,d,e]]
m2 = [[w,x],[x,z],[y,z],[z,w]]

result = simplify_logic(LogMatrixMult(m1, m2)[0][0])
print(result)
```

In the block below using Sympy matrices note that the i,j,k and C, A, B definitions is from me trying to modify to use the iterator, I don't know if this needed or correct.

```
from sympy import And, Xor
from sympy.matrices import Matrix
from sympy.logic import SOPform, simplify_logic
from sympy import symbols, IndexedBase, Idx
from sympy import symbols

def LogMatrixMultArr (A, B):
    rows_A = A.rows
    cols_A = A.cols
    rows_B = B.rows
    cols_B = B.cols
    i,j,k = symbols('i j k', cls=Idx)
    C = IndexedBase('C')
    A = IndexedBase('A')
    B = IndexedBase('B')

    if cols_A != rows_B:
      print ("Cannot multiply the two matrices. Incorrect dimensions.")
      return

    # Create the result matrix
    # Dimensions would be rows_A x cols_B
    C = [[0 for row in range(cols_B)] for col in range(rows_A)]
    for i in range(rows_A):
        for j in range(cols_B):
            for k in range(cols_A):
                # I can add Sympy's in simplify_logic(-)
                C[i,j] = Xor(C[i,j], And(A[i,k], B[k,j]))
                # C[i][j] = Xor(C[i][j],And(A[i][k],B[k][j]))
    return C
b, c, d, e, f, w, x, y, z = symbols('b c d e f w x y z')
P = Matrix([w,x]).reshape(1,2)
Q = Matrix([y,z])
print(LogMatrixMultArr(P,Q))
```

The error I get is: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

```
C[i,j] = Xor(C[i,j], And(A[i,k], B[k,j]))
```

Now I believe I have to do something with some special way of sympy's iterating but am stuck on how to get it to work in the code - if I do even need this methodology.

Also, if anyone knows how to do something such as the above using XOR and And (non-bitwise) instead of + and * operators in a faster way, please do share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with IndexedBase objects. I'm not competent on these but it seems you do not use them right. If you replace

```
    i,j,k = symbols('i j k', cls=Idx)
    C = IndexedBase('C')
    A = IndexedBase('A')
    B = IndexedBase('B')
```

by

```
    C = zeros(rows_A, cols_B)
```

and remove  `C = [[0 for row in range(cols_B)] for col in range(rows_A)]`, then it works.

Comment: Hi esandier. I added the error message. Also, the outer parenthesis didn't do anything, they were remnant from trying other things.