# If matrix_a = [[a, b], [c, d]], and matrix_b = [[w, x], [y, z]] compute matrix_c = [[a*w + c*y, a*x + c*z], [b*w + d*y, b*x + d*z]] in Python 3?

Tags: python, list, matrix, list-comprehension

If I had two matrices matrix_a = [[a, b], [c, d]], and matrix_b = [[w, x], [y, z]] and I wished to find the following matrix matrix_c = [[a*w + c*y, a*x + c*z], [b*w + d*y, b*x + d*z]] how could I do this, not only for this case but for arbitrary sizes of matrix_a and matrix_b:
a) most simply using only list comphrehensions
b) most simply using a function which took the two matrices matrix_a and matrix_b as input, and returned matrix_c
c) and/or an otherwise pythonic manner?

The following code is my current solution.

```
matrix_a = [[1, 1], [2, 1]]
matrix_b = [[25, 1.5], [30, 2.7]]

# so we should obtain matrix_c = [[85, 6.9], [55, 4.2]]

transposed_matrix_a =[list(i) for i in zip(*matrix_a)]

matrix_c = []
for i in range(len(matrix_a[0])):
    def matrix_element(function, number):
        return [function(number)*matrix_b[number][i] for i in range(len(
            matrix_b[0]))]
        
    def t_matrix_a_element(x):
        return transposed_matrix_a[i][x]

    c_vector = [matrix_element(t_matrix_a_element, i) for i in range(len(
        transposed_matrix_a[0]))]
    matrix_c.append([sum(i) for i in zip(*c_vector)])

print(matrix_c)
```

**EDIT:**
To be explicit the desired computation would be:
matrix_c = [[a*w + c*y, a*x + c*z], [b*w + d*y, b*x + d*z]]
matrix_c = [[1 x 25 + 2 x 30, 1 x 1.5 + 2 x 2.7], [1 x 25 + 1 x 30, 1 x 1.5 + 1 x 2.7]]
matrix_c = [[85, 6.9], [55, 4.2]]

**and not the product:**
[[a*w + b*y, a*x + b*z], [c*w + d*y, c*x + d*z]]

Comment: Your code really calculates `[[85, 6.9], [55, 4.2]]`, but I think it is not `[[aw + ay, bx + bz], [cw + cy, dx + dz]]`, that would be `[[55, 4.2], [110, 4.2]]`.

Comment: @tevemadar Apologies yes, I got that muddled up, I've edited the question now, it's matirx_c = [[aw + cy, ax + cz], [bw + dy, bx + dz]] NOT matrix_c = [[aw + ay, bx + bz], [cw + cy, dx + dz]]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> matrix_a = [[a, b], [c, d]]
> matrix_b = [[w, x], [y, z]]
> matrix_c = [[aw + cy, ax + cz], [bw + dy, bx + dz]]
> ```

`abcd` and `wxyz` are not very helpful, especially when someone wants to generalize the task, it's better rewritten with indices, something like

```
A = [a b] = [A11 A12],   B = [w x] = [B11 B12]
    [c d]   [A21 A22]        [y z]   [B21 B22]

C = [a*w+c*y  a*x+c*z] = [A11*B11+A21*B21  A11*B12+A21*B22]
    [b*w+d*y  b*x+d*z]   [A12*B11+A22*B21  A12*B12+A22*B22]
```

then there is any chance for observations like

```
Cij
C11 = A11*B11+A21*B21 = Sum Ak_*Bk_ for k=1,2 and _ could be either i or j
C12 = A11*B12+A21*B22 = Sum Aki*Bkj for k=1,2
C21 = A12*B11+A22*B21 = Sum Aki*Bkj for k=1,2
C22 = A12*B12+A22*B22 = Sum Ak_*Bk_ for k=1,2
Cij = Sum Aki*Bkj
```

something you probably knew, though went ahead with plucking our eyes out with that `abcdwxyz` monstrosity instead.

And that's a matrix multiplication, just not a simple `A*B`, but `AT*B`.
Then you can fetch a multiplying code from [Matrix Multiplication in pure Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508021/matrix-multiplication-in-pure-python) for example, and write

```
matrix_a = [[1, 1], [2, 1]]
#matrix_a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
matrix_b = [[25, 1.5], [30, 2.7]]

transposed_matrix_a =[list(i) for i in zip(*matrix_a)]
transposed_matrix_b =[list(i) for i in zip(*matrix_b)]

print([[sum(ele_a*ele_b for ele_a, ele_b in zip(row_a, col_b)) 
        for col_b in transposed_matrix_b] for row_a in transposed_matrix_a])

a,b,c,d=sum(matrix_a,[])
w,x,y,z=sum(matrix_b,[])
print(a*w+c*y,a*x+c*z)
print(b*w+d*y,b*x+d*z)
```

Will produce

> ```
> [[85, 6.9], [55, 4.2]]
> 85 6.9
> 55 4.2
> ```

(the commented `1,2,3,4` matrix is there for verification purposes, as the original one has a lot of 1s inside and certain indexing issues could go unnoticed)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for non-numpy:
(believe it's more Pythonic ... ;-)    -than numpy version)

```
def matrix_mul(A, B):
    zip_b = list(zip(*B))
    return [[sum(a * b for a, b in zip(row_a, col_b))
                 for col_b in zip_b]
            for row_a in A]

# one-liner
""" result = [[ sum(a*b for a,b in zip(X_row,Y_col))
                        for Y_col in zip(*Y)]
              for X_row in X]
                    
"""
```

Comment: Thank you this indeed seems Pythonic and is exactly the sort of concise code I had in mind... however both solutions in this code return [[55, 4.2], [80, 5.7]] whereas the desired output is [[85, 6.9], [55, 4.2]] . I think that you have computed [[bw + dy, bx + dz], [cw + dy, cx + dz]] and not [[aw + cy, ax + cz], [bw + dy, bx + dz]].

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But if you check the matrix multiplications formula, the answer is correct then.  Please double check - https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/linear-algebra

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I went to the link you said and chose matrix multiplication, which returns [[55, 4.2], [80, 5.7]] the same as your code. But the question is not to compute the product of matrix_a and matrix_b, it's to compute matrix_c = [[aw + cy, ax + cz], [bw + dy, bx + dz]]. The product is [[aw + by, ax + bz], [cw + dy, cx + bz]].

Answer (score 0):

For the (c) case you can simply use the `numpy` module.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 1]])
b = np.array([[25, 1.5], [30, 2.7]])

print(a @ b)

[[55. ,  4.2],
 [80. ,  5.7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
def transpose(matrix):
    # if you just want to iterate over the 
    # transposed matrix, you can just
    # return zip(*matrix)
    return list(map(list, zip(*matrix)))

matrix_c = []

for row_a in matrix_a:
    row_c= []
    for val_a, row_b in zip(row_a, transpose(matrix_b)):
        val_c = sum(val_a * val_b for val_b in row_b)
        row_c.append(val_c)
    matrix_c.append(row_c)

print(result)

# [[55, 4.2], [110, 4.2]]
```

Another way, though it is manual, and can not be automated, but just in case:

```
>>> [[a, b], [c, d]], [[w, x], [y, z]] = matrix_a, matrix_b

>>> matrix_c = [[a*w + a*y, b*x + b*z], [c*w + c*y, d*x + d*z]]

>>> matrix_c
[[55, 4.2], [110, 4.2]]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I asked the question incorrectly and what I meant to ask is different if you'd care to look again? I meant matirx_c = [[aw + cy, ax + cz], [bw + dy, bx + dz]] NOT matrix_c = [[aw + ay, bx + bz], [cw + cy, dx + dz]].

Creating a function called transpose as you suggest is more readable I'll do that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to the question which is totally based on list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

#mat_a = [[1, 1], [2, 1]]
#mat_b = [[25, 1.5], [30, 2.7]]
mat_a = np.random.random((3,4))
mat_b = np.random.random((4,5))

def matMul(A, B):
    return [list(map(lambda x:sum([i*j for i,j in x]), [list(zip(row, col)) for row in A for col in [list(i) for i in zip(*B)]]))[s*len(B[0]):s*len(B[0])+len(B[0])] for s in range(len(A)) ]

print(mat_a @ mat_b)
for row in matMul(mat_a, mat_b):
    print(row)
```